# Game physics of tearing apart

Tags: physics, simulation

For a game I'm programming I'm looking for a kind of realistic mechanic for simulating the tearing apart of objects. Let me explain:

I have a given point $p$ in a 2-dimensional space (possible later also more dimensions so a solution should be scalable, which i assume is not the problem) and I have a number of forces $ f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n$ acting on this point $p$. So normally this point moves over time according to the combination of this forces. But now I'm looking for a kind of realistic mechanic that if forces vary strongly the point/objects gets split up in two points/objects that move in different directions.

Here a simple visual example:

[image]

three "similar" forces resulting in one single force (the point will move according to this single vector)

[image]

three forces that "tear" the point apart and result in two vectors (point will be split up in two new points that move according two the respective vector)

I amuse we need two give the point some kind of inner force, that defines how easy it is to tear the point apart?

By kind of realistic I mean something that doesn't need to be extremely realistic according to the real world physics but something that would fell kind of real in a video game. So an additional benefit would be that it can be easily computed.

Comment: Given two force vectors $f_1,f_2$, the force of tension within the object is the magnitude of the vector $f_2 - f_1$. A reasonable condition for whether the object splits might be whether this difference between two forces (among all pairs of forces) surpasses some threshold corresponding to the object strength